# MySQL / MariaDB - Start multi-source replication with mariabackup (xtrabackup)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, replication

Many times I successfully performed procedure described in the https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-a-replication-slave-with-mariabackup/ - it's fastest and easiest because replica is restored by copying files and binlog coordinates for CHANGE MASTER are saved in xtrabackup_binlog_info file.

With multi-source replication it seems to be not possible, because both backups from masters contain their own ibdata1 file - so I cannot restore them into single instance of MySQL (the future slave).

The only way I can think of is like that:

- restore 1st master into slave
- enable replication for selected databases from 1st master
- restore 2nd master into second slave (temporary)
- use mysqldump to move selected databases from temporary slave into main slave

The problem is that databases on both masters are large (~1 TB) and mysqldump/restore takes ages - and chasing few days of stalled replication (between backup and restore) takes additional significant amount of time. I'd really like to avoid this.

I know that with MyISAM tables I could just move table files but it's innodb and it cannot be changed.

Maybe there's some way to merge ibdata1 files? Or maybe export/import ibdata1 dictionaries related to chosen databases?

Answer (score 0):

There's no tricks that can be done with ibdata1 files.

Look at using mydumper for parallel extraction and load.

[pt-data-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) is a way to replicate the data with inbuilt protections against databsae delay. I don't know if it supports multisource